# Replacing Items on the Settings Menu

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-actions

I am trying to replace the "Site contents" link on the Settings Menu.  I want to put a new link in the same position with a different action.  I'm having trouble targeting items correctly.  The following site has useful information but it seams incomplete because I can't find the right selectors.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730.aspx

In the picture you can see that "Site contents" and "Andrew's Test" appear in the menu.
I have three issues:

1. The HideCustomAction doesn't have the right target.  I have tried adding and removing parameters.  I really can't confirm that GroupId, Location or HideActionID are correct; the code below is my best guess based on the site above and Google.
2. The CustomAction is displaying in the wrong place.  Based on Sequence, I would expect "Andrew's Test" to be the first item.  However, in the picture you can see that it is 8th.
3. Are there any debugging tools?  Visual Studio doesn't seam to be very helpful when it comes to making custom actions.

Please help me resolve these problems.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">


  <CustomAction
    Id="{FF401381-CEC8-4DDB-ACBB-A0D6E2578EDE}"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    GroupId="SiteActions"

    Title="Andrew's Test"
    Rights=""
    Sequence="1"
  >
    <UrlAction Url="_layouts/CP.SharePoint.SiteStyles/styleweb.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>




  <HideCustomAction
    Id="HideSiteContents"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    HideActionId="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
    >
  </HideCustomAction>



</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Short answer is, "Site contents" in the gear icon is not editable with CustomActions... or at least I never figured it out.  In order to solve the problem I used jQuery and, the slightly obscure, "AdditionalPageHead" DelegateControl.

My users really like the 2010 version of the "Site content" page and really, really hate the 2013 version.  So, I just copied "viewlsts.aspx" from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\layouts" on a 2010 Server.
Below is a picture of my solution and the important code.

[image]

**Add_to_Delagate\Elements.xml**:
("AdditionalPageHead" is the Delegate I am targeting.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead"
           Sequence="90"
           ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/SiteContentFixer/SiteContentFixer_jQuery.ascx" />
</Elements>
```

**Scripts\Elements.xml**: 
('Url="Scripts"' is where the library is set; I am expecting a library named "Scripts" at the root site of every Site Collection.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">   <Module Name="Scripts" Url="Scripts">
    <File Path="Scripts\SiteContentFixer.js" Url="SiteContentFixer.js" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>   </Module> </Elements>
```

**SiteContentFixer.js**:

```
var Atec = Atec || {};
Atec.SiteContentFixer = function() {
    'use strict';

    var context;
    var web;

    function init() {
        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        web = context.get_web();

        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }

    function onSuccess() {

        $("[id*='MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents']").attr("onmenuclick", "STSNavigate2(event,'" + web.get_url() + "/_layouts/SiteContentFixer/viewlsts.aspx');");

    }

    function onFail(){

    }


    return{

        load: function () {
            /* On some Pages SP.SOD happens before SharePoint has loaded and sometimes it happens after
                If before, then _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames waits until SharePoint loads and init is called while there is nothing to change.
                If after, then  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames does nothing because it's the point where the pushed functions are called.  However, init has a target now.

            */
            _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Atec.SiteContentFixer.start");  

            init();
        }
        ,

        start: function(){

            init();
        }

    }

}();   

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Atec.SiteContentFixer.load);
```

**SiteContentFixer_jQuery.ascx**:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>  <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteContentFixer_jQuery.ascx.cs" Inherits="SiteContentFixer.ControlTemplates.SiteContentFixer.SiteContentFixer_jQuery" %>



<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<%=SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl %>/Scripts/SiteContentFixer.js"   />
```

**viewlsts.aspx**:
(This is the 2010 version of the file.)

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ViewListsPage"   EnableViewState="false"    %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="TopNavBar" src="~/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBarButton" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBarButton.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ViewHeader" src="~/_controltemplates/ViewHeader.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="wssawc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_pagetitle_doclist%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_pagetitle_doclist%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"><SharePoint:AlphaImage src="/_layouts/images/allcontents.png" Height="54" Width="145" Alt="" runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script>
// <![CDATA[
        var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser_ListOLists";
// ]]>
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="LabelPageDescription" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId ="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server">
 <div class="ms-titleareaframe"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId ="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server">
 <div style="height:100%;" class="ms-titleareaframe"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId ="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
 <div style="height:100%;" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='10' height='1' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId ="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
 <div style="height:100%;" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='10' height='1' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
    <wssuc:TopNavBar id="IdTopNavBar" runat="server" Version="4" ShouldUseExtra="true"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server"/>
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <asp:SiteMapPath
            SiteMapProvider="SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            id="ContentMap"
            SkipLinkText=""
            NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-die"
            PathSeparator="&#160;&gt; "
            PathSeparatorStyle-CssClass = "s4-bcsep"
            runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
            runat="server"
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            PathSeparator=""
            CssClass="s4-breadcrumb"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
            SkipLinkText="" />
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <wssuc:ToolBar id="ToolBar" CssClass="ms-menutoolbar" ButtonSeparator="<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' />" runat="server" FocusOnToolBar = true>
        <Template_Buttons>
            <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" id="diidIONewList" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_new_ak%>"  ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/createcontent.gif" ShowImageAndText="true" HoverCellActiveCssClass="ms-buttonactivehover" HoverCellInActiveCssClass="ms-buttoninactivehover" />
            <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                runat="server"
                id="diidIOSiteWorkflows"
                ShowImageAndText="true"
                CssClass="ms-wkflwbtn"
                AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_SiteWorkflow_ak%>"
                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                ImageWidth=16
                ImageHeight=16
                OffsetX=0
                OffsetY=642
                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_siteworkflow%>"
                NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/workflow.aspx"
                PermissionsString="EditListItems, AddAndCustomizePages"
                PermissionMode="Any"
                HoverCellActiveCssClass="ms-buttonactivehover"
                HoverCellInActiveCssClass="ms-buttoninactivehover" />
        </Template_Buttons>
        <Template_RightButtons>
            <SharePoint:TemplateBasedControl TemplateName="AllContentViewSelector" runat="server"/>
        </Template_RightButtons>
    </wssuc:ToolBar>
    <table cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="ms-viewlsts">
        <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" nowrap>&#160;</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" nowrap><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_title%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" nowrap width="40%"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_desc%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="text-align: right;" nowrap width="3%"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_items%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" nowrap width="25%"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_lastmodified%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                </tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
        <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <tr class="ms-vh2-nobg">
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="white-space:nowrap;">&#160;</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="white-space:nowrap;" title="<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat='server' text='<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_title%>' EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>">&#160;</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="white-space:nowrap; width:40%;" title="<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat='server' text='<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_desc%>' EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>">&#160;</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="text-align: right; white-space:nowrap; width:3%;"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_items%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" style="white-space:nowrap; width:25%;"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_lastmodified%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></th>
                </tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
<%
DateTime dtCurrent = DateTime.UtcNow;
string alternatingClass = (null != SPContext.Current.Web && SPContext.Current.Web.UIVersion < 4) ? "ms-alternating" : "ms-alternatingstrong";
if (!bShowSites)
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerator myRgs = rgRgs.GetEnumerator();
    int j = 0;
    while (myRgs.MoveNext())
    {
            SPBaseType currBaseType = (SPBaseType)myRgs.Current;
            myRgs.MoveNext();
            SPListTemplateType currListTemplate = (SPListTemplateType)myRgs.Current;
            myRgs.MoveNext();
                    String strBaseType=(String)myRgs.Current;
            myRgs.MoveNext();
                    String strNoBaseType=(String)myRgs.Current;
            myRgs.MoveNext();
            myRgs.MoveNext();
            ArrayList currList = (ArrayList)myRgs.Current;
            System.Collections.IEnumerator currRg = currList.GetEnumerator();
            if (!bBaseTypeInited ||
               (spBaseType == currBaseType && spListTemplate == currListTemplate))
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
    %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-gb" colspan="5">
                           <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                              &#160; <%SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strBaseType,Response.Output);%>
                           </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    <%
                        j = 1;
                }
                else
                {
    %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-gb"  colspan="5" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                           <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                              &#160; <%SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strBaseType,Response.Output);%>
                           </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    <%
                }
    %>
    <%
                if (currList.Count == 0)
                {
    %>
                    <tr><td class="ms-vb2 ms-viewlsts-noitems" colspan="6">
                        <%SPHttpUtility.NoEncode(strNoBaseType,Response.Output);%>
                    </td></tr>
    <%
                }
    }
    %>
    <%
            string rowClass = alternatingClass;
            while (currRg.MoveNext())
            {
                int iList = (int)currRg.Current;
                SPList spList = (iList>=spLists.Count )? spListsIssue[iList - spLists.Count ]  : spLists[iList];
                if (spList.Hidden)
                {
                    continue;
                }
    %>
                    <tr class="<%=rowClass%>">
                        <td class="ms-vb-icon">
                        <%
                            string listViewUrl;
                            try
                            {
                                if (spList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary)
                                {
                                    listViewUrl = GetRootFolderOfList(spList);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    listViewUrl = spList.DefaultViewUrl;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                listViewUrl = "";
                            }
                            if (listViewUrl == "")
                                listViewUrl = "ListEdit.aspx?List=" + spList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                        %>
                              <a id=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode("viewlist" + spList.BaseTemplate.ToString()),Response.Output);%> href=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(listViewUrl,true),Response.Output);%> >
                              <img border="0" alt=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(spList.Title),Response.Output);%> src=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(spList.ImageUrl,true),Response.Output);%> width="16" height="16" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2" >
                              <a id=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode("viewlist" + spList.BaseTemplate.ToString()),Response.Output);%> href=<%SPHttpUtility.AddQuote(SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(listViewUrl,true),Response.Output);%>><%SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(spList.Title,Response.Output);%></a>&#160;
                        </td>
                        <%
                            string listDescription;
                            listDescription = ListPageBase.RenderListDescription(Web, spList);
                        %>
                        <td class="ms-vb2" width="40%" >
                              <%SPHttpUtility.NoEncode(listDescription,Response.Output);%>&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2" width="3%" align="<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat='server' text='<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_align%>' EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>">
                        <%
                            if (spList.DataSource != null)
                            {
                                bShowExternalDataListCountInfo = true;
                                %>
                                <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_ExternalDataList_CountExternal%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncodeAllowSimpleTextFormatting'/>
                                <%
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SPHttpUtility.NoEncode(spList.ItemCount,Response.Output);
                            }
                        %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2" width="25%" >
                            <nobr>
                           <%
                           SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(SPUtility.TimeDeltaAsString(spList.LastItemModifiedDate, dtCurrent),Response.Output);
                           %>
                            </nobr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    <%
                rowClass = (rowClass == "")? alternatingClass : "";
                    }
    }
}
if (!bBaseTypeInited || bShowSites)
{
    %>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-gb" colspan="5" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                           <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                              &#160; <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_sitesandworkspaces_title%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
                           </h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
    SPWebCollection webs = Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
    if (webs.Count==0)
    {
        %>
            <tr><td class="ms-vb2 ms-viewlsts-noitems" colspan="6">
        <% if(Web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageSubwebs)) { %>
                <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_L_szNoSites_Text%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncodeAllowSimpleTextFormatting'/>
            </td></tr>
        <% } else { %>
                <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_L_szNoSites1_Text%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncodeAllowSimpleTextFormatting'/>
            </td></tr>
        <% }
    }
    string rowClass = alternatingClass;
    foreach (SPWeb webToDisplay in webs)
    {
        string imageUrl;
        string toolTip;
        Pair webImageData = SPUtility.MapWebToIcon(webToDisplay);
        imageUrl = (string)(webImageData.First);
        toolTip = SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)(webImageData.Second));
        string destUrl = SPHttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(webToDisplay.Url + "/",true);
    %>
             <tr class="<%=rowClass%>">
                <td class="ms-vb-icon" >
                      <a id="webIcon" href="<%=destUrl%>"  >
                      <img border="0" alt="<%=toolTip%>" src="<%=("/_layouts/images/"+imageUrl)%>" width="16" height="16" /></a>
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" >
                      <a id="webUrl" href="<%=destUrl%>"><%SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(webToDisplay.Title,Response.Output);%></a>&#160;
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" width="40%" >
                      <%SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(webToDisplay.Description,Response.Output);%>
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" width="3%"></td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" width="25%" >
                    <nobr>
                   <%=SPUtility.TimeDeltaAsString(webToDisplay.LastItemModifiedDate, dtCurrent)%>
                    </nobr>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <%
    rowClass = (rowClass == "")? alternatingClass : "";
    }
}
if (bShowRecycleBin)
{
%>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-gb"  colspan="5" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                           <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                              &#160; <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_recyclebin%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
                           </h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb-icon" >
                  <a id="viewlistRecycleBin" href="RecycleBin.aspx" >
                  <img border="0" alt="<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat='server' text='<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_recyclebin%>' EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>" src="/_layouts/images/recycbin.gif" width="16" height="16" /></a>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2" >
                  <a id="viewlistRecycleBin" href="RecycleBin.aspx"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_recyclebin%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/></a>&#160;
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2" width="40%" >
                  <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_recyclebin_description%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2" width="3%" align="right">
                  <%
                  SPHttpUtility.NoEncode(Convert.ToString(RecycleBinItemCount),Response.Output);
                  %>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2" width="25%" >
                <nobr>
               &#160;
                </nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
<%
}
%>
    </table>
    <div class="ms-vb2">
<%
if (bShowExternalDataListCountInfo)
{
%>
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_ExternalDataList_CountNotAvailable%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncodeAllowSimpleTextFormatting'/>
<%
}
%>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```